# How to change colors of a line graph JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, graph, charts, line

I'm making a stock market game and I'm using the JavaFX line chart to show trend lines and estimated price movements, and currently I'm only getting an orange line, and it doesn't match the theme of the rest of the UI.

for reference, the two HEX values that I'd like to stick to are

1 - 46424D

2 - 2F2C38

I've searched the web for ideas, and all things mostly point to using some CSS script that I'm not currently familiar with.

Thanks!

- Kellen Miller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartSample extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart
                = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        series.getNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke: #336699; ");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: so when I try to do that, the window doesn't even open, I added the series, but nothing seems to be occurring.

Comment: @KellenMiller Worked for me in JavaFX8

Comment: Is there a way to change the background of the graph too?

Comment: `Platform.runLater(() -> lineChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background").setStyle("-fx-background-color: #e2ecfe;"));`

Comment: @KellenMiller You can also set these styles through a CSS file, which may be easier. See the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#linechart).

Comment: I agree, you unfortunately can't get away from at least understanding how to add CSS (along side using style classes) to your JavaFX application.